# SQL - time in / out in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Employee_tb**

```
  sqnc_no userid  name  branch    txn_date      task

  1         1       Joe   CA        2020-04-06   sampletask
  2         1       Joe   CA        2020-04-07   sampletask1
```

**Branch_tb**

```
branchcode   branchdesc
CA            SampleBranch
```

**Time_Tb**

```
Userid  Txn_Date                    Status
1       2020-04-06 08:25:23.567     IN
1       2020-04-06 18:15:42.493     OUT
1       2020-04-07 08:25:23.567     IN
1       2020-04-07 18:15:42.493     OUT
```

I have here a sample table which employee has a time in and out, I want to get the time in and out of the employee in one query, can someone help me how to do it? thank you in advance.

Result I want to display:

```
userid   name   branch         txn_date     in/out
1        joe    SampleBranch   2020-04-06   08:25 AM / 6:15PM
1        joe    SampleBranch   2020-04-07   08:25 AM / 6:15PM
```

Comment: What if the times don't line up?  Such as two ins and then an out?

Comment: What happens when employee is "in" in the evening and "out" the next morning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to assign groups of "in"s by using a cumulative sum and then aggregating:

```
select t.id, convert(date, txn_date),
       convert(time, min(txn_date)) as in_time,
       convert(time, max(case when status = 'out' then txn_date end)) as out_time
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'in' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid, convert(date, txn_date) order by txn_date) as grp
      from t
     ) t 
group by t.id, convert(date, txn_date), grp;
```

It is a simple matter to join to the other table to get the name of the employee.

Comment: could you please explain where you want to use `grp`